# Python Selenium - I'm getting StaleElementReferenceException when I get element after clicking button

Tags: python, selenium, exception, staleelementreferenceexception

I tried to make auto ticketing macro using python Selenium, but when it clicks a button, java script in web changes element of page and StaleElementReferenceException just appears when it finds newly generated elements.

How can I fix this exception? I tried to wait until page reloads elements using driver.implicitly_wait(1)

but still it's not working and seems it's not waiting well.

```
for timing in seatTiming.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li"):
    timing.click() # this removes old elements of seatSpace and generates new element
    while len(seatSpace.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")) < 1: # wait until seatSpace gets elements
        driver.implicitly_wait(0.1)
    
    for seat in seatSpace.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li"):
        currentClass = seat.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "strong").text # ERROR
        print(currentClass)
```

Comment: try this approach https://pastebin.com/75LNSzG3 . If it works for you, then I'll post answer here

Comment: or this one https://pastebin.com/gPNiT5PJ. p.s: I am not a python user :)